# Php - allow space in rewriteRule

Tags: php, seo, url-rewriting, space, rule

Hey there at the moment i have this rewrite (for seo) :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?id=$1
```

It works but only with url like this:

```
http://example.com/product/anyProduct
```

But when url is like this:

```
http://example.com/product/any Product
```

There is an space and i get 404 - Error.

So,
how can i replace any space with a "-" ?

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]+)$ index.php?id=$1
```

But this doesnt work for me, any idea? greetings!

Comment: hyphen (`-`) has special mean inside character class (`[]`). You have to escape it

Comment: escape it using "/" like this: ^([a-zA-Z0-9_ /-/]+)$ ?

Comment: You have to read Regex manual. e.g. here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: followed instructions and did it this way: ^([a-zA-Z0-9_ \-\]+)$ => doesnt work, but why?

Comment: you know i just need to replace any space with an "-", is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Try add `+` symbol to regex like `^([a-zA-Z0-9_ \-+]+)$`.

`+` is an urlencoded space.

**UPD**: Try change regex to `^(.+)$` for every symbol

Comment: what do u mean by saying change regex for every symbol??

Comment: Sorry, my English is bad. I mean, that `^(.+)$` regex get line from start to end of a query with any symbols not only `0-9A-Za-z_-`. Urlencoded symbols will be there too and rewriterule will work with this.